# python3 opening files and reading lines

Tags: python-3.x

Can you explain what is going on in this code? I don't seem to understand
how you can open the file and read it line by line instead of all of the sentences at the same time in a for loop. Thanks

Let's say I have these sentences in a document file:

```
cat:dog:mice
cat1:dog1:mice1
cat2:dog2:mice2
cat3:dog3:mice3
```

Here is the code:

```
from sys import argv

filename = input("Please enter the name of a file: ")
f = open(filename,'r')

d1ct = dict()
print("Number of times each animal visited each station:")
print("Animal Id           Station 1           Station 2")

for line in f:
     if '\n' == line[-1]:
          line = line[:-1]
     (AnimalId, Timestamp, StationId,) = line.split(':')
     key = (AnimalId,StationId,)
     if key not in d1ct:
          d1ct[key] = 0
     d1ct[key] += 1
```

Answer (score 8):

The magic is at:

```
for line in f:
     if '\n' == line[-1]:
          line = line[:-1]
```

Python `file` objects are special in that they can be iterated over in a for loop. On each iteration, it retrieves the next line of the file. Because it includes the last character in the line, which could be a newline, it's often useful to check and remove the last character.

Answer (score 7):

As Moshe wrote, open file objects can be iterated. Only, they are not of the `file` type in Python 3.x (as they were in Python 2.x). If the file object is opened in text mode, then the unit of iteration is one text line including the `\n`.

You can use `line = line.rstrip()` to remove the `\n` plus the trailing withespaces.

If you want to read the content of the file at once (into a multiline string), you can use `content = f.read()`.

There is a minor bug in the code. The open file should always be closed. I means to use `f.close()` after the for loop. Or you can wrap the open to the newer `with` construct that will close the file for you -- I suggest to get used to the later approach.